# Erlang - How Can I Parse RFC1123 Dates Into An Erlang Term?

Tags: parsing, date, functional-programming, erlang

Without using a third party module, what steps would I need to take to convert this:

```
<<"Mon, 17 Feb 2014 11:07:53 GMT">>
```

Into this?:

```
[17, 2, 2014, 10, 07, 53]
```

Most of the answers I've Googled suggest using a library.
So far, I suspect I'd get somewhere by pattern matching the formatted date string.

Something like:

```
<<_:5/binary, Date:2/binary>> = <<"Mon, 17 Feb 2014 11:07:53 GMT">>...
```

Which I think should produce the following 'match'

```
Date = 17...
```

That's based on an idea found here - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/erlang-programming/OpXSqt3U86c - Is this a good approach?

Are there any BIF's or modules that can help with this?
And furthermore, how would I convert/map "Feb" to an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try that in the shell:

```
1> <<_:5/binary, Date:2/binary>> = <<"Mon, 17 Feb 2014 11:07:53 GMT">>.
** exception error: no match of right hand side value <<"Mon, 17 Feb 2014 11:07:53 GMT">>
```

Right, we need to match the rest of the binary at the same time:

```
2> <<_:5/binary, Date:2/binary, Rest/binary>> = <<"Mon, 17 Feb 2014 11:07:53 GMT">>.
<<"Mon, 17 Feb 2014 11:07:53 GMT">>
3> Date.
<<"17">>
```

So now `Date` is a binary containing the bytes for the ASCII digits 1 and 7.  We can convert that to a number with `binary_to_integer`:

```
4> binary_to_integer(Date).
17
```

As for the conversion of month names to integers, the usual way to do something like that is with a function:

```
month_name_to_integer("Jan") -> 1;
month_name_to_integer("Feb") -> 2;
...
month_name_to_integer("Dec") -> 12.
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!. Completely forgot about the fact that matches always have to be equivalent. Great answer. :)

As for "month_name_to_integer", would it not be more efficient to use a 'case' statement?

Comment: Take care that with this method you must be sure that the day of the month has always 2 digits, as well as other date fields ("Mon, 03 Feb 2014 01:07:03 GMT").

Comment: @Charlie Both function clauses and case clauses get compiled to the same BEAM code, so it's purely about preference and taste.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [tempo](https://github.com/selectel/tempo) library for datetime formatting and parsing.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bin = <<"Mon, 17 Feb 2014 11:07:53 GMT">>,
L = binary_to_list(Bin),
{match, Res} = 
    re:run(L, "[0-9]+", [global, {capture, all, list}]),
[list_to_integer(X) || [X] <- Res].
```

the output is:

```
[17,2014,11,7,53]
```

Comment: Yes. That's very nice. Though the array order is incorrect. When I first asked the question, I was well aware of at least some of the date parsing libraries, but 1: Would have to hack an application component to use one (Couch DB), and 2: Thought this would be a good way to learn more about best practice. So I'm very grateful for answers like this. The library names won't hurt though. :}

Answer (score 1):

Why suffering? Why not third party module?

I am use [erlware_commons](https://github.com/erlware/erlware_commons)

`ec_date:parse("Mon, 17 Feb 2014 11:07:53 GMT").`