# How to convert a String into an Ecto.DateTime in Elixir?

Tags: datetime, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I need to convert a string containing a valid UTC time to an `Ecto.DateTime` one, which I will insert it into my database with the correct format later. I have tried using the `Ecto.DateTime.cast(date)` method but it doesn't seem to work. The string is `Sat Aug 04 11:48:27 +0000 2012` and comes from the Twitter API.

I know there are libraries such as **Timex** which I didn't inspect yet. Is there any easy working solution already built in Elixir?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**There's no built-in solution** in Elixir or Erlang for parsing `DateTime` values of this format:

```
Sat Aug 04 11:48:27 +0000 2012
```

You can certainly write a parser yourself, but it's neither going to be short or simple. You'll have to split the string, get the values of both date and time parameters, convert month strings to month integers, parse the timezone, represent the complete value in Elixir/Erlang DateTime formats and then finally cast it to `Ecto.DateTime`. See the following links:

- [Elixir Tips - Date Parsing](https://makandracards.com/neoukelixirtips/22065-dates-date-formatting-and-parsing)
- [Erlang - How Can I Parse RFC1123 Dates Into An Erlang Term?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827905/erlang-how-can-i-parse-rfc1123-dates-into-an-erlang-term)
- [Convert timestamp to datetime in erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825151/convert-timestamp-to-datetime-in-erlang)

---

**Using [Timex](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) is the best option here.**

It's a well written library that allows you to stay away from the chaos of inner workings of Date/Time. With `Timex`, you can parse your string like this:

```
"Sat Aug 04 11:48:27 +0000 2012"
|> Timex.parse!("%a %b %d %T %z %Y", :strftime)
|> Ecto.DateTime.cast!

# => #Ecto.DateTime<2012-08-04 11:48:27>
```

---

<sup>*Note: Timex has built-in support for a lot of the common DateTime formats, and I found it weird that a DateTime format being sent by Twitter wasn't supported - so I wrote one for you. Maybe double check to see if your string is correct? Also take a look at Timex [Parsing](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/parsing.html) and [Formatting](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/formatting.html) documentation.*</sup>

Comment: The format sent by Twitter looks actually pretty weird and you're not the first to be surprised, thanks for your input :)