# DateTime in Exlir/Ecto without external dependencies

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a `DateTime` in this format:

```
{{2017, 2, 2}, {14, 43, 50, 0}}
```

I want to convert it to "2 Feb 2017" or "2 February 2017" or "2/02/2017" without using `Timex` or any other dependency except, if needed, `Ecto.DateTime`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

### Using [Ecto.DateTime](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.DateTime.html#to_string/1)

```
{{2017, 2, 2}, {14, 43, 50, 0}}
|> Ecto.DateTime.cast!
|> Ecto.DateTime.to_date
|> Ecto.Date.to_string

# => "2017-02-02"
```

---

### Using [Elixir.Date](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Date.html#)

```
{date, _time} = {{2017, 2, 2}, {14, 43, 50, 0}}

date
|> Date.from_erl!
|> Date.to_string

# => "2017-02-02"
```

---

**Further Modification:**

```
"2017-02-02"
|> String.split("-")
|> Enum.reverse
|> Enum.join("/")

# => "02/02/2017"
```

---

*For a simple case, these might work - but I seriously recommend using [Timex](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) for more complicated ones. [See this answer for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445286/1533054).*

Comment: how about "Feb" or "February"?

Comment: See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

## For String Months

```
defmodule MyDate do
  @months ~w(January February March April May June July August September October November December)

  def to_string({{y, m, d}, _time} = datetime) do
    "#{d} #{Enum.at(@months, m - 1)} #{y}"
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
MyDate.to_string({{2017, 2, 2}, {14, 43, 50, 0}})
# => "2 February 2017"
```

---

*For a simple case, this might work - but I seriously recommend using [Timex](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) for more complicated ones. [See this answer for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445286/1533054).*